# Perform an action based on the page name (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get the name of the current page in JS and check if that name matches a constant. If it does, I want to trigger an alert. I'm able to get the name of the page but there's a problem in the if statement and I'm not sure what it is.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    var sPath=window.location.pathname;
    var sPage = sPath.substring(sPath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    var sHost = 'host.html' ;
    if(spage = sHost){
      alert('orange');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Meh. `spage = sHost` should be `spage == sHost` (or better, `spage === sHost`).

Comment: What a title to a question...

Comment: Just change spage = sHost to spage == sHost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If statement comparison operator should be == or better ===

```
if(spage == sHost){
  alert('orange');
}
```

or

```
if(spage === sHost){
  alert('orange');
}
```

> The strict equality operator === only considers values equal that have the same type.
>
> The lenient equality operator == tries to convert values of different types, before comparing like strict equality.

**Strict equals ===**
Comparing two values. Values with different types are never equal. If both values have the same type then the following assertions hold.

```
undefined === undefined
null === null
```

Two (primitive) numbers:

```
    NaN !== _  // any value including NaN
    x === x
    +0 === -0
```

for any number x. Thus equality is not reflexive in JavaScript, because NaN is not equal to itself.

Two booleans, two strings (primitive): obvious results
Two objects (including arrays and functions): x === y only if x and y are the same object(!). That is, if you want to compare different objects, you have to do it manually.

**Equals ==**
 Essentially comparing two values. If both values have the same type then  compare with == Otherwise:

```
undefined == null
```

If you have one number, one string: convert the string to a number

A boolean and a non-boolean: convert the boolean to a number and then perform the comparison.

Comparing a string or a number to an object: try to convert the object to a primitive and then make the comparison.

Answer (score 1):

In your if statment you are only using one =. This is not a comparator, you hav to use == to check if two vars are equal

```
  <script language="JavaScript">
var sPath=window.location.pathname;
var sPage = sPath.substring(sPath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
var sHost = 'host.html' ;
if(spage == sHost){
  alert('orange');
}
</script>
```

Hope it helped :)